# Define spring bean extending MethodBeforeAdvice that proxies another component

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-aop

For security purposes, I need to wrap/proxy my "@Service" bean with MethodBeforeAdvice that checks that the called method has a `PreAuthorize` annotation.
I have an implementation of `MethodBeforeAdvice` that does the check.

```
public class MethodHasPreAuthorizeAnnotationAdvice implements MethodBeforeAdvice {

    @Override
    public void before(Method method, Object[] args, @Nullable Object target) throws Throwable {
        PreAuthorize securedAnnotation = method.getAnnotation(PreAuthorize.class);
        if (securedAnnotation == null) {
            throw new InsecureMethodException(method.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

I have confirmed that this works as follows :

```
    ProxyFactory factory = new ProxyFactory();
    factory.addAdvice(new MethodHasPreAuthorizeAnnotationAdvice());
    factory.setTarget(customerService);
    securedCustomerService = (CustomerService) factory.getProxy();
```

I have a few requirements :

1. Proxy all my services with this advice. It seems that using an `@Aspect` on the stereotype `@Service` might be the solution to this (see: Baeldung [8. Stereotype Annotations and AOP](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-annotations#annotations))
2. Prefer to limit the use of my services so that access can only generally be obtained through the secured `MethodBeforeAdvice` advised proxies.
3. Preferably enable the original services to be unit testable without the secured proxies (although this is optional as a requirement).
4. Make the secure proxies available through IoC, i.e. `@AutoWired`-able or constructor injected equivalent.

Comment: Looks like that requirement (1) works well and means we don't need to change our @Service(s) and that solves requirement (2).  For requirement (3) we just need to put a boolean property like `my app.services.secured:true` in the @Aspect that can be configured in the application.properties but which defaults to true :
`  @Value("${myapp.secure.services:true}")
    private boolean runSecured;
` but then set this to `false` in the test properties file.  Tests will run fine by default without needing to have the secure test invoked.  Requirement (4) is also satisfied by the solution to (1)

Comment: Sorry, I was very busy in October. I am happy you solved your problems. Please convert your comment into a comprehensive answer. When you have enough reputation points here, you can even accept your own answer and hence mark the question as answered.

Comment: P.S.: Why would you need a property for unit tests? A real unit test would not require Spring at all. If it does, it rather is an integration test or some other intermediate test type like a component or subsystem test. Without Spring, no aspect kicks in and you can easily test your class in isolation, manually injecting the mocks you need via constructors, protected fields or setters.

Comment: P.P.S.: Why did you not use a simple `@Aspect @Component` but decide to manually wire your `MethodBeforeAdvice` into the service? Spring AOP can take care of that for you. Maybe this is what you did in order to address question #1, but I have no way of knowing. Your answer should show how exactly you solved your 4 problems. Then it would be more useful for other readers.